# Delete Data in Two Tables Based on Date in One Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query

I am trying to delete data in a table where a date field value is older than 30 days and also delete related records in a second table that has no date field based on a matching key column in both tables.

Table 1:

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|        Name         |     age          | ExecutionDate|
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|          jack       |     34           | 12/12/2019   |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|          Ryan       |     24           | 10/12/2019   |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
```

Table 2:

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|         city        |     county       | Name         |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|          jersey     |     orange       | jack         |
|---------------------|----------------- |--------------|
|          LA         |     wayne        | Ryan         |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
```

DELETE Statement:

```
delete from table2 where Name IN (select Name from table1 where date < ExecutionDate(day, -30, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Please, add the query you have so far.

Comment: @Ronaldo delete 
```from table1
where Name IN (select Name from table2 where date < ExecutionDate(day, -30, GETDATE()))```. This deletes data only from table2 but not table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward query, however it requires two separate statements, first the DELETE on Table2, then the DELETE on Table1:

```
DELETE 
FROM [Table2] t2
INNER JOIN [Table1] t1 ON t1.[Name] = t2.[Name]
WHERE t1.[ExecutionDate] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());

DELETE 
FROM [Table1] t1
WHERE t1.[ExecutionDate] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
```

I would also like to call out, without knowing the full data model or requirements, there may be data consistency issues introduced by doing this. If you have a record in Table2 for 'John' that has two records in Table1 - one that is 45 days old and one that is 10 days old - the 'John' record in Table2 will be deleted and the link between Table1's 10-day old record and Table2 will be broken because the 'John' record no longer exists.

If you want to preserve the Table2 records if any Table1 records less than 30 days still exist, use something like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM [Table2] t2
INNER JOIN [Table1] t1 ON t1.[Name] = t2.[Name]
WHERE t1.[ExecutionDate] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
   AND t2.[Name] NOT IN (SELECT [Name] FROM [Table1] WHERE [ExecutionDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) AND [Name] = t2.[Name])

DELETE 
FROM [Table1] t1
WHERE t1.[ExecutionDate] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
```

The additional inner SELECT in the WHERE clause checks for Table1 records less than or equal to 30 days old with a matching name to records that are older than 30 days and deletes only those rows in Table2 that do not have a Table1 record less than 30 days old.

Answer (score -1):

With SQL Server HandyD's solution works but you will need to add the alias after the DELETE statement or you will get an error.

```
DELETE t2
FROM [Table2] t2
INNER JOIN [Table1] t1 ON t1.[Name] = t2.[Name]
WHERE t1.[ExecutionDate] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
   AND t2.[Name] NOT IN (
     SELECT [Name] FROM [Table1] 
     WHERE [ExecutionDate] >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) AND [Name] = t2.[Name]
   )

DELETE t1
FROM [Table1] t1
WHERE t1.[ExecutionDate] < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
```